# Mesh networking in boost.Asio

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, distributed-computing

I'm trying to build a mesh network in **`Boost.Asio`**, where each node can talk with each other. Also to a master node, where master sends instructions to different nodes like "*node A do this and ACK me*" or "*node B send data to C and ACK me*". They should be also aware of who is who ( nodes ) and send messages accordingly.

[image]

I am able to make server-single client synchronous system but unable to design and code above mentioned system with `Boost.Asio`.
Need guidance on this.

My network configuration is fixed. I do not have to worry about new nodes joining or leaving.

Comment: Have you looked at [ip multicast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__multicast__join_group.html).  Or.. at a higher level, something like zeroconf or avahi?

Comment: My nodes are fixed.

Comment: The answers I got for my previous question was not 100% correct so I cannot accept it as the correct answer, right? And as far as I know, stack overflow guidelines are that you post new questions if the questions are different.
I have no problem in accepting or voting the answers if it's to the point and straightforward.

Comment: I will not help you on this topic for 2 reasons A- The point raised by @user3666197 is valid, and B- you have not even tried to make a single client/server connection work with asio.  boost.asio comes with examples.  You **must** do some actual work to deserve either a diploma or a salary, and for help on SO as well.

Comment: I actually made a client-server system with Boost.Asio by following the tutorial. I also mentioned it in the question. I also understood I have to somehow make client and server running on the same system.

Comment: Then post some code and explain the problem that stops you. This is how SO works.  Please check the posting requirements, point #6 applies to your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.